# liberty profile default installation location

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty

I have used Eclipse Market place to install the "IBM Websphere Application Server liberty developer tools for Kepler".

Next thing I wish to do is create a New Server. So I right clicked on the Servers tab. New > Server. And create a server of type "WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile". On the second page of the wizard it asks me to choose an existing installation.

Selecting something random for this directory gives an error:
The installation directory is not valid. Check that the path points to a Liberty profile runtime environment (e.g. /wlp).

Where has marketplace installed the liberty profile? Have I even installed the right thing. A simple windows search seems to throw nothing up when I look for wlp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer tools do not include a copy of WAS Liberty itself, it is just the tools to help you develop and deploy applications into a WAS Liberty server. So you have installed the correct thing, but you also need to install a WAS Liberty server as well. The developer tools will install this for you if want.

On the second page, don't select 'existing installation', instead select 'Install from an archive or repository'. Click next, and on the third page, you have the option to 'Download and install a new runtime environment from ibm.com'

Answer (score 0):

"[Download WAS Liberty in Eclipse](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/)" explains the steps for installing Eclipse, the WebSphere Developer Tools, and a Liberty server, with links for the downloads.

"[Installing WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJ1RxHY9Cvw)" on YouTube uses that page and shows how to:

1. Install the WebSphere Developer Tools into Eclipse (which you've already done)
2. Use the tools to install Liberty and create a server

It assumes you already have Eclipse installed.